# adyen encrypted credit card data

Tags: python, python-requests, demandware, adyen

I'm trying to code a script on a sneakers website that supports adyen checkout. Basically, it encrypts my credit card data in this way and doesn't make me pay.

```
payload_cc = {
...
"dwfrm_billing_paymentMethod": "CREDIT_CARD",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_cardType": "Mastercard",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_adyenEncryptedData":"adyenjs_0_1_25$ibmnmdt8wdc5...", 
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_cardNumber":"************last4digits"
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_expirationMonth": "07",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_expirationYear": "2024"
}
```

This is my actual requests for the payment.

```
checkout_page = s.get("https://www.slamjam.com/en_IT/checkout-begin?stage=payment#payment",headers=headers)

checkout_card = s.post("https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/CheckoutServices-SubmitPayment",headers=headers, data=payload_cc)

place_order = s.get("https://www.slamjam.com/en_IT/checkout-begin?stage=placeOrder#placeOrder",headers=headers)
```

The last 2 requests don't go through because adyen encrypts the card number and generates a sort of token. What can I do? Does it exist like an adyen library that can help me?

Comment: Hey did you get solution?

Comment: @Abhay yes i did

Comment: can you please share how?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to build out the connection to Adyen yourself. Adyen provides a cartridge for [Demandware / Salesforce commerce cloud](https://docs.adyen.com/plugins/salesforce-commerce-cloud). It supports card processing out of the box.

You can download the cartridge from the [Adyen github page](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-salesforce-commerce-cloud). This cartridge supports SFRA version 4.x.x and SiteGenesis JS-Controllers.