# Adyen encrypt credit card data [python] [requests]

Tags: python, performance, python-requests

I'm trying to understand how to automate checkout process on a demandware website that uses adyen checkout.

```
payload_creditcard = {
...
"dwfrm_billing_paymentMethod": "CREDIT_CARD",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_cardType": "Master+card",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_adyenEncryptedData":"adyenjs_0_1_18$ibddsadc65...", 
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_cardNumber":"************3345"
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_expirationMonth": "20",
"dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_expirationYear": "2030"
}
```

This is the script for the payment:

```
checkout_page = s.get("https://www.slamjam.com/en_IT/checkout-begin?stage=payment#payment",headers=headers)

checkout_card = s.post("https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/CheckoutServices-SubmitPayment",headers=headers, data=payload_creditcard)

place_order = s.get("https://www.slamjam.com/en_IT/checkout-begin?stage=placeOrder#placeOrder",headers=headers)
```

The problem is that every time the "dwfrm_billing_creditCardFields_adyenEncryptedData" changes every time and I don't know how to generate it. 
I found javascript functions within the website, but to make them work you need an html with the form with the card inputs and obviously I can't insert an html every time I need this token inside the python code, because everything is based on speed. Is there any way you can recommend me or if someone has already done it before?

Comment: You are trying to create a bot to perform purchases on slamjam's website?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand how these types of bots work, but I'm not going to create others, there are enough of them. I would like to understand how developers manage to bypass this type of security every time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adyen encrypted credit card data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664449/adyen-encrypted-credit-card-data)

Comment: No, so I asked again. Unfortunately, the boy managed to find the solution but does not want to share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adyen client js intentionally performs per session, client side encryption to keep a shopper's card information safe, and keep the company's server out of scope for PCI.

If you really need to test this, then you will need to use something like [selenium webdriver for python](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to actually load the page and render the js.